# shared library symbol names

Tags: c++, python, c, interop, ctypes

I would like to be able to use C/C++ functions from python using ctypes python module.

I have a function `int doit()` in the `.c` / `.cpp` file. When I try to load the shared library:

```
Frr=CDLL("/path/FoCpy2/libFrr.so")
Frr.doit(c_int(5))
```

i find it working really well when the `.c` variant is used. When C++ is called the good way to call this function is (found out using `nm libFrr.so` using `nm -gC libFrr.so` produces just plain `doit()`):

```
Frr._Z4doitv(c_int(5))
```

I have read on Stackexchange that there is no standard way to call C++ from python, and there is "nonstandard name mangling" issue. Is the "Z4" a part of that issue? I guess the nonstandard name mangling would appear for more advanced language features such as class methods, templates, but also for such basic functions? Is it possible to force using simple C function names in simple cases for the C++ code?

Comment: extern "C" { your c API } in your header file...

Comment: you should look into the [swig utility](http://www.swig.org/), specifically the [c++/python support part](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extern "C"` to make the functions "look like" C functions to the outside world (i.e., disable name-mangling). And yes, you are correct, name-mangling is needed mostly for the more complicated features and types of functions that C++ has, and the name-mangling scheme has never been standardized (nor the binary compatibility) and so it varies from compiler to compiler and between versions (but most main-stream compilers have settled to something permanent now, but still different between compiler-vendors). And the reason that mangling is also required for plain old free functions is because C++ supports overloading (same function names but with different parameters), and thus, the compilers will encode the parameter specification (e.g., types) into the mangled names. Of course, if you use `extern "C"` you lose all features for which name-mangling is needed, so, it more or less boils down to C functions only.

You can use `extern "C"` either on a per-function basis, like so:

```
extern "C" int doit();
```

Or for the overall header:

```
extern "C" {

// all the function declarations here ...

};
```

However, for Python specifically, I highly recommend that you use a library that allows you to construct Python classes and functions that are a reflection of your C++ classes and functions, that makes life a lot easier and hides away all this extern "C" business. I recommend using [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/), see this [getting started page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/class), it makes exporting functions and classes to Python a breeze. I guess others would also recommend [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), but I have never used it.

Comment: Thinks for both answers. Boost.Python seems very adequate. Thinks again.

Answer (score 2):

Calling c++ library functions is always a mess, actually even if you're using C++ you have to use the same compiler, etc. to make sure it works.

The only general solution is to define your c++ functions as `extern "C"` and make sure you follow the involved limitations - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c) for an explanation of it.